# import common dependencies to package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

At our company we have at the moment 5 web applications that are built using Gulp. For Gulp, we have a common buildfile that all applications use (and override certain parts of it if needed). 
This makes it very easy to add features or fix bugs in all projects at the same time. However, I still need to edit the package.json file in each project separatly if I want to add a new npm dependency or bump a version for an existing one.

What I would like to accomplish is to a "base file" where all the common dependencies are configured, and the I would like to import that into the "local" package.json in each project. It would also be nice if each project could add more dependencies than the ones registered as common.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, and it's a good thing that it isn't. You need to declare your dependencies explicitly on each project.

What you can do, if your build process is a shared API, is to extract your build script into an npm package of its own, and include that in the package.json of all other projects, and use it in them (coding it in a way that allows for overrides)

Then when you need a new dependency for your common build, you only need to change it once. (Note that with this, you'd still need to make sure your build package version is up to date in all other applications)

Comment: While it might be intentional, whether it's "good" or not might be up for some debate.